# Examples of unit vectors that's in the same direction as vector, let's say $v=(1,2,-3)^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Can someone give me some examples of unit vectors that's in the same direction as vector, let's say $v=(1,2,-3)^T$ for:

(i) Euclidean norm

(ii) Weighted norm $||V||^2=2V_1^2+v_2^2+\frac13v_3^2$

(iii) The 1 norm

(iv) The infinite norm

(v) The norm based on their inner product $2v_1w_1-v_1w_1-v_2w_1+2v_2w_2-v_2w_3-v_3w_2+2v_3w_3$.

Ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples? No. The idea? Yes.

If you have a norm $\|\cdot\|$, then the vector you're looking for is $\|v\|^{-1}v$.

For example (but just this one :-P), the Euclidean norm of your vector is

$$\|v\| = \sqrt{1^2 + 2^2 + (-3)^2} = \sqrt{1 + 4 + 9} = \sqrt{14},$$

so the unit vector in the direction of $v$ is $\sqrt{1/14} v = (1/\sqrt{14}, 2/\sqrt{14}, -3/\sqrt{14})^T$.

Knowing this, others shouldn't be too hard. Good luck and ask if you get stuck.

P.S. "The norm based on their inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is given by $\|v\| = \sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle}$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Big Hint: Let $||\cdot||$ designate the desired norm for each subpart of the given problem, then the unit vector in the direction of the vector $\vec{\bf{v}}$ can be computed as
$$\hat{\bf{v}} = \frac{\vec{\bf{v}}}{||\vec{\bf{v}}||}$$